# Lodash or JavaScript equivalent for LINQ Group by & Select FirstOrDefault()

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have **list** of stores which has `AuthorizationOrder`, I will need to pull the `firstOrDefault` values of a grouped collection in JavaScript.

```
eg: storeDto : { StoreNumber = 1 , Warehouse = 4201, AuthorizationOrder = 1 },
               { StoreNumber = 2 , Warehouse = 4201, AuthorizationOrder = 2 },
               { StoreNumber = 1 , Warehouse = 4202, AuthorizationOrder = 2 },
               { StoreNumber = 1 , Warehouse = 4203, AuthorizationOrder = 3 },
               { StoreNumber = 2 , Warehouse = 4207, AuthorizationOrder = 1 }
```

Using LINQ :

```
warehouseStoreList = warehouseStoreList.GroupBy(x => x.StoreNumber)
      .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.AuthorizationOrder).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();


Result: { StoreNumber = 1 , Warehouse = 4201, AuthorizationOrder = 1 },
        { StoreNumber = 2 , Warehouse = 4207, AuthorizationOrder = 1 }
```

How do I do similar operation using `Lodash` or JavaScript to pull data by grouping on store , get first value after ordering on `AuthorizationOrder`.

Also, get the Warehouses with associated stores. Please see fiddle which is implemented using LINQ

Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/glC1ij

Want to achieve same thing with JavaScript or Lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group based on the `StoreNumber`. Create an accumulator with unique each unique `StoreNumber` as key like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "StoreNumber": 1,
    "Warehouse": 4201,
    "AuthorizationOrder": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "StoreNumber": 2,
    "Warehouse": 4207,
    "AuthorizationOrder": 1
  }
}
```

Update the value if the `key` doesn't exist or current `AuthorizationOrder` is less than that of accumulator's. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get just the values to an array:

```js
const array = [{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4201,AuthorizationOrder:1},{StoreNumber:2,Warehouse:4201,AuthorizationOrder:2},{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4202,AuthorizationOrder:2},{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4203,AuthorizationOrder:3},{StoreNumber:2,Warehouse:4207,AuthorizationOrder:1}]

const grouped = array.reduce((acc, o) => {
  let group = acc[o.StoreNumber];
  
  if(!group || group.AuthorizationOrder > o.AuthorizationOrder)
    acc[o.StoreNumber] = o;

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

Comment: can you please answer how to tie up stores to warehouse & remove warehouses if storelist is empty in javascript, attached is the jsfiddle, i am looking for javascript equivalent code

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi this is completely different question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps:

- Apply `reduce()` on array of object and set accumulator to empty object `{}`.
- The keys of object will be `storeNumber` and value will the objects.
- Check if the `AuthorizationOrder` of already present object at particular key is greater than the `AuthorizationOrder` of the element we are iterating then change the value of that key to the current element. Otherwise don't change it.
- At last use `Object.values()` to get an array of objects.

```js
const arr = [{ StoreNumber:1 , Warehouse:4201, AuthorizationOrder:1 },
               { StoreNumber:2 , Warehouse:4201, AuthorizationOrder:2 },
               { StoreNumber:1 , Warehouse:4202, AuthorizationOrder:2 },
               { StoreNumber:1 , Warehouse:4203, AuthorizationOrder:3 },
               { StoreNumber:2 , Warehouse:4207, AuthorizationOrder:1 }]
               
const res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let ao = a.AuthorizationOrder
  let ao2 = (ac[a.StoreNumber] || {}).AuthorizationOrder || Infinity 
  if(ao < ao2) ac[a.StoreNumber] = a;
  return ac
},{});

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: can you please answer how to tie up stores to warehouse & remove warehouses if storelist is empty in javascript, attached is the jsfiddle using LINQ, i am looking for javascript equivalent code

Comment: @Vijender: please ask a new question about that (that would probably be too broad anyway).

Answer (score 0):

With lodash/fp you can group the items by the `StoreNumber`, then map each group to the item with the minimum `AuthorizationOrder` value:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, minBy } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy('StoreNumber'),
  map(minBy('AuthorizationOrder'))
)

const array = [{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4201,AuthorizationOrder:1},{StoreNumber:2,Warehouse:4201,AuthorizationOrder:2},{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4202,AuthorizationOrder:2},{StoreNumber:1,Warehouse:4203,AuthorizationOrder:3},{StoreNumber:2,Warehouse:4207,AuthorizationOrder:1}]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```